# How to add a logic to .pro file based on configuration?

Tags: qt, qmake

In my application (qmake based) I have 2 configuration, let's say CONF1 and CONF2.
Each configuration defines "Additional arguments" at Project/Build settings/Build step tab:

```
DEFINES+=CONF1
```

and

```
DEFINES+=CONF2
```

So in C++ code I can add some specified logic for specified build configuration:

```
#if defined CONF1
logo->setPixmap(QPixmap("conf1.png"));
#else
logo->setPixmap(QPixmap("conf2.png"));
#endif
```

Also I need to define icon for the application executable.
So in .pro file I've added:

```
win32 {
    RC_ICONS = logo.ico
}
```

But the problem that I need different icons for different configuration.

I've tried:

```
contains(DEFINES, CONF1) {
    RC_ICONS = conf1.ico
}
else {
    RC_ICONS = conf2.ico
}
```

but that doesn't work. It looks that `contains` works only for variables defined inside .pro file only.

So my question - how can I add different settings (icons in my case) for different configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware qmake can't evaluate variables set in the DEFINES list, but only qmake variables.

However, you can use a qmake variable to perform both tasks at the same time. Just assign the "conf" value to your variable, evaluate that variable to add it to the DEFINES list and then test its value using qmake functions (e.g. *equals*).

As an example:

Add the following to your additional qmake arguments (including quotes):

```
"MYCONF = CONF1"
```

Then use these directives in your .pro file:

```
DEFINES += $${MYCONF}

equals(MYCONF, "CONF1") {
    RC_ICONS = conf1.ico
} else {
    RC_ICONS = conf2.ico
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergio Monteleone for the response. Where should I set `MYCONF`?

Comment: `MYCONF` is not a keyword, it's just the most original name that came to mind to create a qmake variable. Joking aside, in qmake syntax, you can declare any variable just by assigning a value to it. In this case, we declare the variable `MYCONF` and assign it the value `CONF1`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But if you mean I should define that in .pro I guess it is not what I need. My target is to switch configuration, recompile and so to get a different application - I mean conf1 or conf2, with different icon. If I need to change some variable in .pro after switching configuration it is not what I need.

Comment: As per documentation ([here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-running.html)) you can pass qmake assignment in the additional arguments. Just type there "MYCONF = CONF1" instead of "DEFINES+=CONF1". I have updated my answer to make it clearer.